# “GC overhead limit exceeded” error in grails editor while running Android Project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, grails, garbage-collection

I have setup [GGST](https://spring.io/tools/ggts) and ADT to create Android project there. But while running it just get hanged and responding **"GC overhead limit exceeded"**.

In Eclipse there is file [eclipse.ini](https://docs.oseems.com/general/application/eclipse/fix-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded) I know, but here I just got stuck. Any suggestion where I need to increase memory in GGST editor.

Request: Other IDE I know, but this is specific problem related to GGST editor, so please answer related.

Comment: It will still run in Eclipse IDE JVM, so I would think that you need to increase memory there

Comment: you mean I should update in eclipse.ini ??